# How can I keep absolute path rule to compiled from ts to js file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nodemon

I've set the paths and baseUrl for using absoulte path.

node can't figure the absolute path that I specified when I run the compiled js file.

I think the absolute path rule didn't apply to Nodemon.

any helps..?

below code is the script that I ran.
`"st": "tsc && nodemon --inspect dist/server.js",`

Thank you in advance.

[image]
tsconfig.json

[image]
import crawler

[image]
compiled one

[image]
error

Comment: Please post code as code blocks (surrounded by triple backticks), not as screenshots.

Comment: May I ask why do you prefer code blocks instead of screen shots?
Cuz the reason that I posted screenshots is I though it won't need code blocks to solve this prob.

Comment: @LoganLee It's easier to read. It can be copied and pasted. Lots of reasons to prefer code blocks over screenshots. What do you expect to be at the path '@utils/crawler'?

Comment: I expected tsc will compile absolute path as well to work well.
apparently tsc won't convert absolute path to compiled js .

Answer (score 0):

solved -

use https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias lib.

```
"_moduleAliases": {
        "@utils": "dist/utils/"
    }
```